# Putting the noun "debut" before or after a modifying noun

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

*Excerpted from Cambridge Dictionary:*

> The occasion when someone performs or presents something to the public for the first time
>
> - She made her professional stage debut in Swan Lake.
> - He started as an actor, making his debut as a director in 1990.
> - Her debut album

**I am wondering what the difference is between these two:**

> He started as an actor, making his debut as a director in 1990.

> He started as an actor, making his director debut in 1990.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. He started as an actor, making **his debut as a director** in 1990.

This sentence is perfectly natural.

> 2. He started as an actor, making <sup>?</sup>**his director debut** in 1990.

But in this sentence, ***debut*** is modified by the attributive noun ***director***, which is strange.  People don't normally talk that way.

Instead, people normally use the adjective ***directorial***:

> 3. He started as an actor, making **his directorial debut** in 1990.

Sentences 1 and 3 are both fine and have the same meaning.

---

In this answer, the <sup>?</sup> symbol marks an utterance as questionable, but not ungrammatical.

Comment: +1 You might, however, say that he made his *directing debut*. It's not a participle (the debut didn't direct anything) but a gerund -- so the question is Why is the activity acceptable as an attributive but not the role?

Comment: Because the possessive *blocks*?  Her actor's intuition. Her acting intuition. *Her actor intuition.  ?Her actor-intuition.  Compounding seems to ameliorate the issue.